# How to use filter:blur with clip-path?

Tags: css, css-transforms, shadow, clip-path, css-filters

I'm trying to add a shadow to a `clip-path` hexagon.
Since the usual `box-shadow` (and `filter:drop-shadow()`) won't work with clip-path, I'm trying to fake the effect with a larger pseudo element underneath.
The approach is taken from [here](https://codepen.io/Flashman/pen/ZGrZxN) and works just fine in a simpler example:

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.rectangle {
  margin: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 25%;
}

.rectangle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(10px) brightness(20%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
</div>
```

However using the exact same approach with a clip-path hexagon fails.
This rough sketch shows the desired effect:

[image]

Instead I get:

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.hexagon {
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(0, 229, 154);
  margin: 10%;
}

.hexagon::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(10px) brightness(20%);
  transform: scale(2.5);
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">
</div>
```

Two Questions:

1. How can I make this work?
2. What's a better way to fake shadows for clip-path elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the opposite layout.

The container (in this case, the base element) must have the filter applied, the inner part (in this case, the pseudo) must have the clip property:

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.hexagon {
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px red);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10%;
}

.hexagon::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(2.5);
  z-index: -1;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  background: rgb(0, 229, 154);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's (again) for your help @vals. Looks like I did not express myself well enough. I added a sketch to the question to clarify the desired effect (a shadow behind the hexagon). See what I mean?

Comment: Well, I just copied the filter in the question. But, if you need a drop-shadow, just set it. I have edited my answer